# YouTube-Downloader HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, http, error-handling, pytube

My code worked yesterday but when I try to run it I get an error

```
from pytube import YouTube

#ask for the link from user
link = input("Enter the link of YouTube video you want to download:  ")
yt = YouTube(link)

yt_streams = yt.streams
```

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b722fa04aa86> in <module>()
      7 yt = YouTube(link)
      8 
----> 9 yt_streams = yt.streams

12 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

this is the error I get I am using python 3.9.5 and pytube 10.8.1

Comment: What happen if you try to access this url using web browser?

Comment: Do you understand what "HTTP Error 404: Not Found" means? Did you consider the possibility that the URL is incorrect?

Comment: Please provide the input you have used

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `pytube` is `10.9.3`. To get this you can just run `pip install --upgrade pytube`. However at this time this upgrade won't fix the issue as the `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` is the same. This is a reoccurring issue with the `pytube` package by the way which seems to be fixed after each update but then after a while this starts happening again.

While `pytube` may be attractive to use, I believe is it... You can probably use an alternative which is `youtube_dl`. I've found this to be more reliable than `pytube`.

You can check out their offical [website](https://youtube-dl.org/) and how to [install](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/).